# Two Arrays merged to one; while sum the attributes; with nodes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, merge, count, sum

I have two arrays from mongodb's and i want to merge them.

They look like this:

```
a=[{country: 'de', count: 7},{country: 'es', count: 1}]
b=[{country: 'de', count: 2}, {country: 'us', count: 3}]
```

And what i need is this:

```
c=[{country: 'de', count: 9},{country: 'us', count: 3},{country: 'es', count: 1}]
```

Is there a smart way without looping every possible key pair to accomplish this with nodejs?

*(I could do it with many "for's" but i try to avoid that cuz the code would have many many many of them then.)*

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly ad hoc, but this is how I'd do it.

```
a = [{country: 'de', count: 7}, {country: 'es', count: 1}]
b = [{country: 'de', count: 2}, {country: 'us', count: 3}]

temp = {}
c = []

merger = function (entry) {
    key = entry.country

    if (typeof temp[key] == 'undefined')
        temp[key] = 0

    temp[key] += entry.count
}

a.forEach(merger)
b.forEach(merger)

for (country in temp) {
    c.push({ country: country, count: temp[country] })
}
```

I've tested this in Node's REPL. Note that you can extend this to more arrays with `c.forEach(merger)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried it with my data and it works perfectly for me.